# no puedo conectarme a mi base de datos en postgres

Tags: postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Intento conectarme y me sale ese mensaje. Ya probé cambiándole por "trust" en el archivo pg_hba, también probé iniciando nuevamente en "servicios" y tampoco dio resultado. Ya no sé que hacer

Comment: Tal como se te ha indicado en tu [pregunta anterior](/q/611122) (al cual aún no has respondido en los comentarios, por cierto), muestra tu error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta y agregar más detalles.

Comment: Y por cierto, ¿está corriendo el servicio de PostgreSQL en tu máquina?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.